Is there a list of all the sources Rav Moshe Ben Maimon takes his halachot from in the Yad Chazakah (Mishneh Torah)?
I am learning the Yad Chazakah (also known as the Mishneh Torah). I want to study the sources each halakha is taken from and attempt to get in the mind of Rav Moshe Ben Maimon and see if I can understand any consistent patterns in his methodology of paskening. To do this I need to be able to look at the sources of each halakha. A friend suggested to me to work through the Talmud and collect the references from one of the commentaries there that point to the halakhot in the Yad Chazakah. However, while this was a very useful suggestion I would like to go in the other direction. I would like to read the Yad Chazakah in order and be able to check the discussions in the sources as I read through it. What would be the best way to go about this? Does anyone know a resource which links each halakha in the Yad Chazakha to its source in Chazal?

Wonderful that you are doing this. To understand the Rambam's methodology you will benefit from reading his Introduction to the Mishna, available on Sefaria, as well as his introduction to Mishne Torah, available there as well. To review his rulings on the gemara, you might want to use the Koren edition of the Talmud which lists the rulings of Rambam on every page (not just the reference, like the Vilna gemara does, but the actual ruling translated into English)

The challenge of "working backwards" from the Mishne Torah is that at times the sources are spread over multiple tractates of the Talmud. In any case, whatever you do start in one well-defined area so you have a chance to "wrap your mind around it"

@shmosel that question seems to be within the same printed text. this is looking for even an outside recourse

Most of the primary commentaries do this.

Rav Chaim Kanievsky's Kiryat Melech sources the Rambam's Halachot. Controversially, he even included the Zohar for sources.

@Yehuda Where does the Arizal contend that?
